# JSON View not rendering a list of ObjectIds as string

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Having a weird issue when trying to render out a domain object.

so I have a courses domain

```
class Course {
    ObjectId id
    List<ObjectId> lessonIds

    static embedded = [
        'lessonIds'
    ]
}
```

Where I have a search that returns the results to the json view

```
model.details = [
    results       : courses.count,
    courses       : courses.elements,
    resultsPerPage: courses.limit,
    currentPage   : courses.page,
    nextPage      : ((courses.page * courses.limit) < courses.count) ? courses.page + 1 : courses.page,
    previousPage  : Math.max(1, courses.page - 1),
    firstPage     : 1,
    lastPage      : Math.round(Math.ceil(courses.count / courses.limit)),
    message       : ''
]

render(view: view, model: model)
```

and build the view like so

```
import grow.enums.MimeTypesEnum

response.status OK
response.contentType(MimeTypesEnum.JSON.value)

model {
    Map details
}

json g.render(details)
```

The issue comes when it renders out and the output looks like the following where the lessonIds are not being tostring'd correctly

```
{
  "results": 1,
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": "5ec2c1355dcc962c2057e58a",
      "lessonIds": [
        {
          "currentCounter": -1932751946,
          "time": 1589821749000,
          "timeSecond": 1589821749,
          "counter": 5760393,
          "generatedMachineIdentifier": 6147222,
          "machineIdentifier": 6147222,
          "date": "2020-05-18T17:09:09Z",
          "generatedProcessIdentifier": 15660,
          "processIdentifier": 11296,
          "timestamp": 1589821749
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resultsPerPage": 100,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "nextPage": 1,
  "previousPage": 1,
  "firstPage": 1,
  "lastPage": 1,
  "message": ""
}
```

Not sure why that is happening but I do have a work around that works by doing a collect on the results and toStringing them before they get to the view

```
courses.elements.each{
    it.lessonIds = it.lessonIds.collect{it.toString()}
    it.discard()
}
```

Just not sure if this is the best way or if there is some way to do this in the json view.

Comment: I don't think `static embedded = ['lessonIds']` will have any affect on anything since `lessonIds` is a `List`.  Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: I also may be wrong but I think the static is needed to indicate a keyword instead of specific parameter.

Comment: `embedded` does need to be `static` when it is used but I am saying I don't think it has any affect in a situation like this (embedding a property that is a `List` or any other `Collection` type).  Are you seeing that `embedded` changes anything in this particular context?

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now. In this case no, the `embedded` does not change it one way or the other.

Comment: David B - Apologies.  On closer inspection of your question, it is probably safe to assume that you are using MongoDB, in which case the `embedded` attribute is sensible.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No worries dude, thank you for taking a moment to look at it at least